# I deleted my user folder using terminal on macos

Tags: time-machine

Can anyone tell me how to restore my user folder using time machine backup.

I deleted my user folder in macos and do not know how restore it using time machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Finder, open your boot volume, then in list view navigate into Users.

From there use the menu bar item 'Enter Time Machine'

That will list all users as at the last backup. Select yours & restore.

[image]

If you cannot authorise this, then you will have to do a full recovery from the last Time Machine backup.